# SSIS SQL Task Map Result Set to Project Parameter

Tags: ssis

I am implementing a custom auditing framework, logging ETL events such as start, end, error, insertrows etc.

As well as logging at a package level, I'm implementing "session logging" where a sequence of package executions, i.e. a controller package that executes several packages, is a session. In order to keep track of the "session", the stored procedures always return a SessionLogID.

I was hoping I could map this result set to a project parameter as otherwise, I will have to save it to a user var and then pass it around between packages via parameters. This will mean every single package will have a Package Parameter and User Variable called SessionLogID. I don't want to do this if I don't need to.

Open to other suggestions.

Thanks,
Adam

Answer (score 0):

Parameters cannot change at runtime. They are a set once kind of deal whereas variables can change at any time. You can set the variable once in the parent package and map the variable to the child package's using a parameter.

Comment: That's understandable except for the fact that as far as I can see, SSIS doens't have global variables that can be accessed across several packages within a project (if this is not true, please let me know!). Unfortunately, your suggestion won't work for my issue as due to the nature of logging, there is distinct parent and child package(s), the parent package, or rather the "initiation" of the session is simply whichever package is executed first. As a a result, every package needs a configurable parameter and then a variable to output to with the result set of the SQL task.

Comment: Why not create your own "global variable" by storing the session Id in a database and having every package start by querying that data?